# Why doesn't `packadd` work with packer?

Tags: packages, packer

Say you have a bunch of packages installed with `packer`. I inspected the file structure and it seems to me they are in the format of native Vim packages. Great news! That means we should be able to:

```
nvim --clean
:packadd [some-package]
```

and get all of its commands and functionality.

But it doesn't work :( What is the technical reason for this, I feel like the above approach would be super useful for isolating the behavior of a package

Comment: The plugin's issue tracker seems like a better fit for that question, don't you think?

Comment: @romainl Affirmative!

Comment: https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim/issues/1167